# Differential equations and linearly independent solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $$y_1(x)=\sin 2x$$ and $$y_2(x)=\cos 2x$$ are two solutions of $$y^{,,}+4y=0,$$ show that $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linearly independent solutions.

I think to prove linearly independent,the equation will be
$$c_1\sin 2x+c_2\cos 2x=0$$,where $c_1$ and $c_2$ have to be equal to zero,but how to prove that??,please help me..

Comment: Take some values for x . For instance you can try $2x=\pi /2$ and $x=0$

Comment: Or use the Wronskian to show linear independence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to show the independence of solutions is to show that the Wronskian is not identically zero.

$$ W= \det \begin {bmatrix}y_1&y_2\\y'_1&y'_2\end{bmatrix}\not = 0$$

You can take it from here.

Comment: It is a determinant...right??

Comment: Yes it is a  determinant. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$c_1\sin 2x+c_2\cos 2x=0,  \forall x$$
for $x=\frac {\pi}4$
$$\implies c_1=0$$
for $x=0$
$$\implies c_2=0$$